# JQuery - Text Slideshow and Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Jquery fading text in a loop question.

Hi there - I have a jquery fading text, looping like a slideshow question.

I am using this code to fade quoted text in and out of a div box.

I have multiple div boxes throughout my site.

Some of my divs are different sizes - so I have to make different classes in the css .

My question is two fold.

Is there a way I can tweek this jquery code so it can effect all the classes at the same time - so I don't have to have a separate script for each class?

Jquery Code:

```
$("document").ready(function($){
    var i = 0;
    var delay = 3000;
    var items = $(".content");
    items.eq(0).show();
    var len = items.length;
    setInterval(function () {
        items.filter(":visible").fadeOut(function () {
            items.eq(++i % len).fadeIn();
        });
    }, delay);
});
```

My second question 
- what is the best css option for making the text scalable and responsive.
Some of the famouse quotes are very long - and some are short.

A Pre-thanks for any advice!!!

Example: 
*Bear in mind - I have a lot of these - each with slightly different size box.

Comment: Since you can add as many classes as you need to an element, I would solve your first problem by setting the CSS for each as needed, then adding a single class like "fade_text" or something, to all of the elements you want to fade. This way, they can all have different style definitions, but since they share a common class as well, they will all be effected by fading the "fade_text" class... hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help - thats what I did and it's working great.

Comment: I just found out I have to make these fades accessible to IE7. Can you give me some help to make these jQuery Transitions work with IE7 Please?

Comment: I am afraid things are a bit hectic right now. So, the best I can do it to point you to the animate() jquery function instead of using fadeIn/Out: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and to also suggest you assign a variable to your interval so it does not get garbage collected and stop working randomly. So, the interval would be this: var intrvl = setInterval(function () {
        items.filter(":visible").fadeOut(function () {
            items.eq(++i % len).fadeIn();
        });
    }, delay);

Comment: Thanks for the lead, but I went through the code and it seems to he working now. I am linking to a jquery v1 cdn, using the same code I had.

Comment: Though I am running into other ie7 related issues, if I cannot find an answer I will ask for help in a different post since it is unrelated. Thanks again!